# Override 'all' method of a model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Account` model that has columns:

```
id :bigint(8)
name :string
```

In `app/models/account.rb`, I have:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :logo
end
```

This is an API, and the controller only returns JSON. In my controller, I have:

```
render :json => Account.all
```

The code above returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Example2"
  }
]
```

I want to also include the url of the `ActiveStorage` file attached to the JSON returned.

In order to achieve that, I am doing this in the controller:

```
def index
  @accounts =  
    Account.all.map do |account|
      account =
        account.attributes.merge(
          :logo_url =>
            account.logo.attached? ?
              polymorphic_url(account.logo) : nil
        )
  end

  render :json => @accounts
end
```

This will return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example1",
    "logo_url": "/path/to/logo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Example2",
    "logo_url": "/path/to/logo.jpg"
  }
]
```

However, I don't want to do this whenever I call `Account.all`; I want to automatically add the `logo_url` whenever `Account.all` is called.

I have come up with this solution; instead of calling it in the controller, I decided to override the method in the model. In `app/models/account.rb`, I added:

```
def self.all
  super.map do |account|
    account =
      account.attributes.merge(
        :logo_url =>
          account.logo.attached? ?
            polymorphic_url(account.logo) : nil
      )
  end
end
```

The code above works so well. The problem is that methods `find`, `find_by`, `where`, and other methods stopped working. And if I remove the `self.all` method from `account.rb`, it works again.

The following codes:

```
Account.find_by :id => params[:id]
Account.find params[:id]
```

raise an error:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x00007fd09b68d670>
```

I believe this happens because `self.all` returns an array instead of an active record.

How can I override the `all` method in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to override `Account.all`.
Instead you want to change the default serialization of your model.
Try this:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :logo

  private

  def serializable_hash(options)
    super(options).merge("logo_url" => logo_url)
  end

  def logo_url
    logo.attached? ? polymorphic_url(account.logo) : nil
  end
end
```

The controller ends up calling `to_json` on your model and the will end up using the `#serializable_hash`. Since `to_son` takes options to set a root of the json, it's best to override `serializable_hash`.   Another approach is to create a separate serializer classes per model but this should be suitable for a simple case.

Comment: Can you show how to implement it in the controller?

Comment: I believe it will work in the controller because the controller will try to serialize the models and call `to_json` on them which will invoke the new code.